# Exclude .svn folders within git

Tags: svn, git

I'm trying to exclude subversion's folders from being tracked by git. I tried a couple different setups for .git/info/exclude, but it doesn't seem to work. I would use git-svn, but it's a pain to request access to get that to work, so I'd rather just work around this by excluding the folders.

I want to exclude ".svn/entries"

I've tried adding the following lines to .git/info/exlude:
.svn
entries
.svn/entries
*entries*
*svn*

No matter what I try, .svn entries shows up when I run git status

Comment: what do you mean its a pain to request access to get git-svn to work. git-svn just issues svn commands so if you already have SVN access you can use git-svn without anyone upstream knowing at all or needing to change anything

Comment: Access to install things on my work computer. There's a perl module missing, and to ask the admins to make that mod, is just a pain...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think you want to use a .gitignore file in your top-level directory. This will work if you put ".svn/entries" on a line in that file. You might just put ".svn" instead of ".svn/entries" as well.

EDIT: See comments. If they files are already being tracked by git, they'll always show up in `git status`.

Comment: I tried this too, and this didn't work. The problem is that each folder has its own .svn/entries.

Comment: This works for me, even in the presence of one in each folder. Are the entries showing up in `svn status` because you've already asked git to track them? If you've `git add`ed them, they'll show up no matter what. Just `git rm --cached` them and you'll be OK.

Comment: There it is. I started by adding all the files in trunk... Good catch Jesse!

Comment: Not the most elegant thing in the world, but I used the following to recursively strip .svn folders (as per @JesseRusak): `for dir in $(find ./ -type d); do git rm --cached -r $dir/.svn; done;`

Comment: I just removed all the old .svn directories using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1294608/308315

Comment: ghayes's rule is dangerous and potentially a security issue if someone has placed filenames with commands embedded in them.  Or it might just fail because for example a filename has a space in it.  I suggest this variant instead:  `find ./ -type d -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --cached -r`

Answer (score 30):

This thread has the correct answer:

[Git - Ignore certain files contained in specific folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971465/git-ignore-certain-files-contained-in-specific-folders)

What you really need is:

```
.svn*
```

Answer (score 25):

Put ".svn" in a `~/.gitexcludes` file. Then tell git about it:

```
echo '.svn' > ~/.gitexcludes
git config --global core.excludesfile "/home/USER_NAME/.gitexcludes"
```

(Make sure you change USER_NAME so it points to your home directory)

Comment: Casey, I really thought that was going to work...but alas it didn't. This is pretty frustrating.

Comment: What is the difference between `.gitexcludes` and `.gitignore`?

Comment: @Shurane See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066749/git-excludes-vs-ignores -- excludes are not versioned, ignores are.

Comment: Worked. Note: it should be "~/.gitexcludes"

Answer (score 5):

This following structure and .gitignore contents worked for me

- \.git
- \.svn
- \.gitignore

#### .gitignore contents

```
.svn/
.gitignore
```

Comment: [Don't tell Git to ignore the `.gitignore`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767147/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-gitignore)

Answer (score 3):

Do what `Casey` suggests, except name the file `.gitignore` and put it in the root of your git repo.

I also like to do a `attrib +h .gitignore` so it won't show up in my explorer windows.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to keep the svn directory.

you may run the following first:

```
for dir in $(find ./ -type d -name \*.svn); do git rm --cached  -r $dir; done;
```

and then run `echo ".svn" >>.gitignore`   in the root directory

Answer (score 2):

since every versioned folder has a .svn directory you have to put:

*/.svn/*

Comment: This doesn't work. It will ignore `src/.svn` and `coolStuff/.svn` but not `src/main/.svn`.

Comment: for multiple folders the "**/*" is the way to go! than you need two lines in .gitignore: "*/.svn/*" and "**/.svn/*"

Comment: for subfolders exclusion use : **/.svn/