# Git Ignores and Maven targets

Tags: git, maven-2, version-control, gitignore

Anyone know if it is possible to ignore all the instances of a particular directory in a file structure managed by git.

I'm looking to exclude all the 'target' folders in a maven project with a number of submodules. I know I can explicitly exclude each of them in a top level .gitignore, but I'd really like to be able to specify a pattern like **/target/* there to have it automatically ignore the instance in sub directories?

Is this possible?

Comment: With what configuration are you making this work? */.settings/* would only ignore 'xxx/.settings/*', not '.settings/*' or 'xxx/yyy/.settings/*': the ignore patterns do not seem to be applied recursively. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971465/git-ignore-certain-files-contained-in-specific-folders .

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It is possible to use patterns in a `.gitignore` file. See the [gitignore man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). The pattern `*/target/*` should ignore any directory named target and anything under it. Or you may try `*/target/**` to ignore everything under target.

Comment: Thanks! Here for anyone else, is contents for a .gitignore to skip the ususal maven & eclipse suspects.

target/*
*/target/*
.metadata
*tar.gz
.classpath
.project
*/.settings/*

Comment: With what configuration are you making this work? */.settings/* would only ignore 'xxx/.settings/*', not '.settings/*' or 'xxx/yyy/.settings/*': the ignore patterns do not seem to be applied recursively. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971465/git-ignore-certain-files-contained-in-specific-folders .

Comment: For multi-module projects you may want to use _**/target/_, but be careful not to exclude legitimate "target" directories in the sources

Comment: `/target/**` works in `\.git\info\exclude` file a well.

Comment: Just tried to commit a java project with "target" subpackage in one of it's modules. :(

Answer (score 241):

The `.gitignore` file in the root directory *does* apply to all subdirectories.  Mine looks like this:

```
.classpath
.project
.settings/
target/
```

This is in a multi-module maven project. All the submodules are imported as individual eclipse projects using m2eclipse.  I have no further `.gitignore` files.  Indeed, if you look in the [gitignore man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html):

> Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file
>   in the same directory as the path, *or
>   in any parent directory*…

So this should work for you.

Comment: That is a better answer than '*/target/*'. It does exclude a directory wherever it is located in the tree of directories. But it would not work for files (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971465/git-ignore-certain-files-contained-in-specific-folders )

Comment: if you continue reading it says "These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file." Your answear is wrong...

Comment: I use this approach and use "target/" to ignore all maven build folders, however be careful that you risk to ignore code that is located in packages containing a "target" folder in their path. 

(In a project with the following classes: `src/main/java/org/example/game/archery/bow/LongBow.java`
 and `src/main/java/org/example/game/archery/target/Target.java`, your would find nothing to hit with your LongBow with such .gitignore configuration :-) )

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed out in comments by Abhijeet you can just add line like:

```
/target/**
```

to *exclude* file in `\.git\info\` folder.

Then if you want to get rid of that `target` folder in your remote repo you will need to first manually delete this folder from your local repository, commit and then push it. Thats because git will show you content of a target folder as modified at first.

Comment: The additional action set me straight.  I added target/ but the directory continued to exist in the repo.  Once removed from the repo, the target folder was never re-added.

Answer (score 4):

add following lines in gitignore, from all undesirable files

```
/target/
*/target/**
**/META-INF/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans
.sts4-cache

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

### NetBeans ###
/nbproject/private/
/build/
/nbbuild/
/dist/
/nbdist/
/.nb-gradle/
```

Answer (score 2):

I ignore all classes residing in target folder from git. 
add following line in open .gitignore file:

*/*.class

OR

*/target/**

It is working perfectly for me. try it.

Answer (score 0):

For the **`Spring Tool Suite`**, Add the following ignore resources to `.gitignore` file and commit into the repository

```
*.classpath
*.class
*.prefs
*.jar
*.lst
*.project
*.factorypath
*.original
target/
.settings/
.apt_generated
.sts4-cache
.springBeans
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi-module repositories, in addition to @Gleidosn answer I would add the following expression to take into consideration the nested target folders:

```
**/target/
```