# Issue with ignoring subdirectory in git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a maven multi-modules project which has a depth of around 5 levels.
I'm now moving to git and I see that a lot of the content of the `target` folder is captured by git as "Unstaged Changes".
I've googled a lot and searched SO but couldn't find an answer as to how to get git to ignore the **entire** directory tree of the `target` folder.
My `.gitignore`, which resides at the root of the project, looks like this:

```
.project  
.classpath
.settings/
target/
```

The strange thing is that the `.class` files, which reside somewhere under the `target` tree, do get ignored by the above definitions but files like `MANIFEST.MF`, `pom.properties` or my own application properties files which are located somewhere in the `target` directory tree are not ignored.
I've read [Git Ignores and Maven targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991801/git-ignores-and-maven-targets) but that solution does not seem to work for me.
I can also say that when I try to add `target/*` rule it doesn't change anything and when I replace `target/` with the `target/*` then the `.class` files appear as unstaged as well.
I'd really appreciate some guidance as it seems very unlikely to me that the hordes of people using git and maven haven't already resolved similar issues. Thanks.

Comment: Did you commit any of those files in `target/` directory to your repository before? Adding file to `.gitignore` has no effect if the file is already tracked by git.

Comment: @KL-7 My partner made the initial commit but that actually sounds like it might be the issue. I'll check and report back. If so you can post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

One of the reasons might be that you already committed that files to your repository. In that case adding them to `.gitignore` doesn't prevent git from tracking these files. To fix that you should first remove them from repository like that:

```
git rm -r target/
```

(If your project has modules, you need to include the path down to the relevant module's target:
`git rm -r parent_project/module_name/target/`)

If you want to remove directory from repository but not from disk you can use `--cached` option:

```
git rm -r --cached target/
```

In any case you should then commit that deletion to the repository (you can do it in the same commit with adding `target/` to `.gitignore` if you wish).

Comment: Sorry for the noob but when I do `git rm -r --cached target/` does it only delete in my local repository? If so, then I later need to push the local repository to my remote repository, right?

Comment: Yes, first you need to commit that changes and then push to remote repository.

Comment: I haven't forgotten. I'm having some problems with this issue but I think it's relating more to my current inexperience with git than your solution. I'll post back/accept your answer once I can. Thanks.

Comment: Key additional gotcha - "One of the reasons might be that you already committed that files to your repository. In that case adding them to .gitignore doesn't prevent git from tracking these files." many thanks

Comment: From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) "The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked. To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached."

Comment: Being struggling to find the problem for the last hours failing to see that I committed the "Target" folder. Thank you!!

Comment: I failed to see that i previously already committed the target folder, thank you very much this helped me alot !

Answer (score 6):

```
target
target/*
```

Add these lines in the gitignore to ignore the target file and all the files inside target. This should not track that folder and its content anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, using [tortoisegit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) on folder target simply choose "Delete and add to ignore list".