# Remove long path from m2e-wtp in git repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

I have setup a new repository and made an initial commit. It is a Maven web-app/Java project.

Unfortunately the repo shows a long path for the m2e-wtp. It's the path of the m2e directory on my local Ubuntu machine. How can I remove this long path?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sur you have a .gitignore file at the root of your project or git repo, which should contain target/ on one line.

See [Git Ignores and Maven targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991801/git-ignores-and-maven-targets) for more information