# target/ vs /target/ in .gitignore

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using Eclipse (this is probably irrelevant) and I want to exclude Maven target folder from commit.

There are [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991801/git-ignores-and-maven-targets) of notations

1. `/target/**`
2. `*/target/*`
3. `/target/**`
4. `target/`
5. `/target/`

What is the difference?

And what is the exact meaning of each of them?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: you probably want `/target/`.

## Long

Let's start with a clear definition of the *work-tree* (from [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary), where it is spelled [**working tree**](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_working_tree)):

> The tree of actual checked out files. The working tree normally contains the contents of the [HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_HEAD) commit’s tree, plus any local changes that you have made but not yet committed.

We need to keep in mind that what Git stores, and exchanges with other Git repositories, are *commits*.  Each commit freezes, for all time, some set of files so that at any time in the future, you can tell Git *get me commit `a123456...`* and get all your files back as of the time you made commit `a123456...`.  (Each commit has a unique, big-and-ugly hash ID like this, which you'll see in `git log` output and elsewhere.)

#### Commits vs the work tree

The files inside commits are stored in a special, Git-only, compressed, de-duplicated, and read-only form.  I like to call these files *freeze-dried*.  They literally *cannot* be changed.  So they're fine for archival, but completely useless for getting any actual *work* done.  Git therefore needs to be able to *extract* any given commit, "rehydrating" the freeze-dried files and turning them back into ordinary everyday files that you can see and use and work with.  The place you put these files is the *work-tree* or *working tree*.

The working tree of course has a top level directory (or folder if you prefer that term), in which you store various files, including your main `.gitignore` file.  That top level directory can have sub-directories (sub-folders) and each sub-folder can have its own `.gitignore` file too.  This is important when you ask about `/target` vs `target`, for instance.

#### Gitignore entries

An entry in a `.gitignore` file can be in any of the following forms:

- `name` (with no special characters like `*`)
- `name.*` or `*.txt` or even `name*txt`
- `folder/`
- `folder/*`
- `folder/name`
- `folder/name*txt` or any of these variants
- `folder/subfolder/`
- `folder/subfolder/*`
- any of the above prefixed with a slash, e.g., `/name` or `/folder/` or `/folder/name`
- any of the above, including prefixed-with-slash, that are then also prefixed with `!`, e.g., `!/folder/name`

This is not meant to be an *exhaustive* list (you have listed several other forms), but rather to illustrate a few basic principles:

1. A simple file name means *any file or directory with this name*.
2. A name *suffixed* with a slash means *any directory (folder) with this name*.  Entities that are files don't match this kind of entry.
3. Entries can have *embedded* slashes—slashes that are not at the front, and not at the rear, such as `folder/name`.
4. Entries can have *leading* slashes, such as `/name` or `/folder/`, or *both* leading slashes *and* embedded slashes, such as `/folder/name`.
5. Entries can have *glob* characters, `*` and `**`, in various places.
6. Entries can be prefixed with `!`.

The rules for gitignore entries get pretty complicated, but start out simple enough.  Remember that the `.gitignore` could be in the top level folder of your work-tree, or in some sub-folder!

- A plain name, with no embedded or leading slashes, matches any file or folder anywhere from this folder or any of its sub-folders.
- A slash-suffixed name, with no embedded or leading slashes, matches any folder (but not file) from this folder or any of its sub-folders.
- If an entry has a slash prefix *or* an *embedded* slash—either one suffices—the entry matches only files and/or folders in *this* folder.  Hence `folder/name` and `/folder/name` mean *the same thing:* match a file (or folder) named `folder/name` in *this* folder—i.e., the place containing the `.gitignore` file.  Do not match the file `sub/folder/name`, for instance.
- If an entry ends with a trailing slash, it only matches folders (regardless of anything else).

You said:

> I want to exclude Maven target folder

This requires answering a sub-question: *Where does this Maven target folder exist?  Is there only one such folder, or can there be `target/` entities in sub-folders?*  (There's also a separate issue, which is that `.gitignore` directives don't mean quite what people think they mean, and that you need to pay attention to what's in your *index*, but we'll leave that for another section.)

If this means: *Don't include anything in `target` at the top level of my work-tree, but do go ahead and include, e.g., files named `sub/target/file`* then you should use:

```
/target/
```

as the full rule in the `.gitignore` in the top level of your work-tree.  It's slightly redundant since you already know that `/target` *is* a folder, but it expresses clearly that you want to ignore the *folder* named `target` in the top level of your work-tree.

If this means: *Don't include anything in `build-artifacts/target/`*, then you can put:

```
build-artifacts/target/
```

or:

```
/build-artifacts/target/
```

into the top-level `.gitignore`; *or* you can put:

```
/target/
```

into `build-artifacts/.gitignore`.  The one in `build-artifacts/.gitignore` needs a leading slash because `/target/` has no *embedded* slash, while the one in the top level `.gitignore` does not require a leading slash because it has an embedded slash.

If, on the third hand (first foot?), the requirement is to ignore *all* files in *any* folder whose folder-path *contains* a `target` component—e.g., you not only want to ignore `target/file` but also `sub/target/file2` and `sub/target/sub2/file3`—then you should use:

```
target/
```

as your `.gitignore` entry, probably at the top level of your work-tree.

#### The role of the index / staging-area

The `.gitignore` files are about things in your *work-tree*, but Git does not build new commits *from* your work-tree.  Instead, Git builds new commits from an intermediate thing that it calls, variously, the *index* or the *staging area*.  (These two terms refer to the same entity.)

While the index has some other roles, its main one, especially for our purposes here, is that it holds a copy of every file *from* the original commit you extracted, or an updated copy or a totally new file.  That is, if you extracted a commit that had *just* the two files files `file1` and `folder/file2`, your index would now have copies of `file1` and `folder/file2` in it.

The copies inside the index are in the same freeze-dried format as the copies inside a commit.  The difference is that you can *replace* the copies in the index—or add to them, or even subtract them away.  That is, you can run `git add file1` to take the *useful* version of `file1` in your work-tree, freeze-dry it, and stuff that into the index.  You can do the same with `folder/file2`, and you can put *new* files like `folder2/file3` or `./file4` too.  What `git add` does, in short, is to freeze-dry the work-tree version of the file and stuff it into the index.

When you run `git commit`, Git simply packages up everything that's in the index *right then* and make the new commit from that.  So that's why you have to `git add` files all the time: every time you change the work-tree copy, you need to update the index copy, otherwise Git won't save the new version: Git will just re-save the old version again.  (To save space, commits that save the same version of an old file really just *re-use* the old freeze-dried file.  They can do that *because* these files are read-only.  It's always safe to locate an old copy and re-use it, because by definition, everything inside Git is frozen for all time.  Only the index and work-tree copies can be changed!)

In other words, you can think of the index as the *proposed next commit*.  You copy files into it to update the *proposed next commit*.  To remove a file entirely *from* the proposed next commit, you use `git rm --cached` or `git rm` (without `--cached`): Git will remove the file from the index, and maybe from the work-tree too, and now your proposed next commit just doesn't have the file at all.

A file can be in the index / staging-area *and* in the work-tree.  That happens all the time.  Such a file is called *tracked*.  The contents don't have to match: it's just the fact that the file is in the index *right now*, and also in the work-tree, that makes the work-tree file tracked.

If a file is tracked—if it's in the index *right now*—then nothing you do with a `.gitignore` will affect it at all.  To make it *not* tracked, you have to remove it from the index.

If you remove the file from the index—or if it's already not in the index now because it wasn't in the commit you checked out earlier—then the work-tree copy is *untracked*.  **Now** the `.gitignore` entry matters.  The `.gitignore` entry tells Git:

- *Don't complain about this file.*  Normally, `git status` would whine at you, telling you that the file is untracked and, gosh golly gee, shouldn't you `git add` it?  The `.gitignore` makes Git shut up about that file.
- *Don't automatically add this file.*  If you use `git add .` or `git add *` or something like that, you're telling Git: *add everything.*  The `.gitignore` modifies this to be: *add everything—**except** these untracked files that are also ignored, don't add those!*
- It has a third effect, which is to give Git permission to *clobber* the work-tree file in some (rare-ish) cases, and to change the way `git clean` works with `-x` and `-X`.

Really, the file should not be called `.gitignore`, but rather something like `.git-dont-whine-about-these-files-and-do-not-auto-add-them-either-and-maybe-occasionally-do-clobber-or-clean-them`.  But who wants to type that in all the time?  So, `.gitignore`.

#### Conclusion

There is even more to know about `.gitignore` entries, but this is already long enough (maybe too long).  The summary version is:

- `.gitignore` only affects *untracked* files;
- it's mainly about shutting up whining, and avoiding auto-adding; and
- use a trailing slash to mean *directory* / *folder* (whichever word you prefer) and a leading slash to mean *as found in **this** directory*.  When you have complex entries (with embedded slashes), the leading slash is redundant, but conveys your intent.

If you *don't* want the leading-slash effect, but *do* need embedded slashes, you either have to distribute your ignore entries to sub-directories / sub-folders, or use the `**` notation (as a leading component) to match any number of path components.  Otherwise there's rarely any need for `**` at all.

Not covered here: once Git realizes it doesn't have to *read* a work-tree directory, it doesn't bother reading it.  As a result, ignoring a subdirectory generally makes it impossible to un-ignore (with `!` rules) anything *within* the subdirectory.