# Why is SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege ignored on Windows 8?

Tags: windows

I'd like to enable my standard user account (i.e. not elevated) to be able to call CreateSymbolicLink.

However, on Win8, even adding "Everyone" to the SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege ("Create Symbolic Links" in secpol.msc) under local group policy still results in STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD. Why?

[image]

Comment: Silly question, are you running `cmd` as Administrator?

Comment: This setting works for me, when the user in question is a standard user (in Users, not Administrators), but when the user is in Administrators, creating Symlinks is subject to UAC.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I'm explicitly trying to configure my local security policy so creating Symlinks doesn't require elevation

Comment: @ChristianKlauser Are you saying that UAC is hard-coded to trump what's in the local GP?

Comment: Apparently if the user is in the administrator's group they have to Run as Administrator to use MKLINK.  If you remove the user from Administrators apparently all the above works.  See also http://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user

Comment: Isn't this a mishap by Microsoft ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is indeed UAC, as Christian suspected.

[MSDN: Windows Vista Application Development Requirements for User Account Control Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx):

> What privileges the filtered token contain are based on whether the original token contained any of the restricted RIDS listed above (ed: AKA if you're a non-elevated Admin). If any of the restricted RIDs were in the token, **all of the privileges are removed except**:
>
> - SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
> - SeShutdownPrivilege
> - SeUndockPrivilege
> - SeReserveProcessorPrivilege
> - SeTimeZonePrivilege

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Is this configurable or did Microsoft hard-code this set of retained privileges? Having `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` on that list would be nice.

Comment: I can verify that once UAC is disabled, I'm able to create symlinks, even from my main account that has admin rights. Wooohoo!

Comment: FYI, you can double-check your own privileges in use with `whoami /priv`.

Comment: I have a bizzare situation. I believe one of the Insider Preview's changed the Token behavior. i have a VM with non-insider preview Windows 10 and I cannot create symlinks without using Run as Admin. I've turned off UAC, put uses in the Group Policy and still doesn't work. On another machine I have what I believe is the same setup but it has the latest Insider Preview build. And it allows me to create symlinks WITHOUT Run As Admin. Ideas?