# symbolic links on Windows

Tags: android, windows, gradle, symlink

I try to create symbolic link on Windows (as 1st answer to [Is there any way to integrate Eclipse with Gradle in Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912393/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-eclipse-with-gradle-in-android-project))

On linux it is

```
ln -s src/main/res res
ln -s src/main/AndroidManifest.xml AndroidManifest.xml
```

[Windows 7 has `mklink` util](http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-create-symbolic-link-in-windows-7/), but it just did not work on my PC.

I found a great [Junction util](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) and could do `junction res src/main/res`, but for link to file is created .lnk file (aka Windows shortcut).

I discovered that [Git Bash](http://msysgit.github.io/) can execute `ln -s src/main/AndroidManifest.xml AndroidManifest.xml` but it creates copy, not link.

Comment: Does `whoami /priv` show that your access token has `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`? If not, try again in an elevated command prompt. `mklink` should work if the privilege is listed.

Comment: That's great. Even when running as Administrator I have "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege" as disabled. That is clue why it has failed. Now I have other question how to enabled it, but for this question it would be good to accomplish using `mklink`.  So the answer should be use mklink and check "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege" with `whoami /priv`

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320550/secreatesymboliclinkprivilege-ignored-on-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

Use [elevated-command-prompt](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/783-elevated-command-prompt.html)

If error, check "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege", possibly turn off UAC.

Comment: I don't recommend disabling UAC. The privilege to create symbolic links, like most other privileges, gets stripped from an administrator's access token until you elevate to get a privileged token. That's a good thing. If that annoys you, instead use a limited user account that you grant `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`.

Comment: I generally agree, but in my case SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege is disabled even in elevated command prompt. Is there way to grant SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege to particular user?

Comment: The group policy editor, gpedit.msc, is used to grant privileges to a user account.