# Map include path to different directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I am looking for a way to tell CMake to make an include directory appear under another name to the compiler.

Let's say I have a project that needs code from a foreign library. This code resides in a directory foreignLib-1.5.0_build123456 in my project's root directory. From time to time I will want to update this library and in this process change the library directory name.

I want to reference this directory as foreignLib in my C++ source files. I want to be able to write

```
#include "foreignLib/include/lib.h"
```

and CMake should tell my compiler to translate this to

```
#include "foreignLib-1.5.0_build123456/include/lib.h"
```

Now I am wondering:

- Does a feature like this exist in CMake?
- If yes, how do I use it?
- If yes, which compilers are supported?

Comment: If you're on a Unix-like operating system, you should seriously consider doing this with symbolic links (in the file system).

Comment: This projects aims to be cross-platform so using OS dependant features is not an option. Also, this is using git as version control and it doesn't seem like git can store symbolic links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link

Comment: NTFS has symbolic links since Windows Vista.

Comment: @Chris: Have you actually read the accepted answer to the question you referenced? It states that git _can_ store symlinks and handles them just like one would expect. But for cross-platform projects, this is of course not an option.

Comment: @arne Yes, indeed, my bad. I read git stores symlinks as blob and expected it to just copy the link target, but on closer examination it only copies the symlink information and not the target. But still, the problem with incompatible filesystems remains. Git does not use NTFS symlinks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662868/what-happens-when-i-clone-a-repository-with-symlinks-on-windows

Comment: @Chris Yeah, this is not cross-platform safe, especially if you have to support NTFS and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at Cmake's configure_file: Rename your source file into `yourfile.cpp.in` and do

```
#include ${DIR_TO_LIB}/include/xy.h
```

In your CMakeLists, you set the variable `DIR_TO_LIB` somehow (by parsing command line or something) and issue

```
configure_file(yourfile.cpp.in, yourfile.cpp)
```

This will yield `yourfile.cpp` with the correct path set.

This is probably not exactly what you intended, but I think it would work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably just copy the entire include directory into my build tree and make that available.

A decent way of doing that is to use [`file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3afile) to gather a list of files in the includes folder, then use [`configure_file(<input> <output> COPYONLY)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file) to copy them to the build tree.

By using `configure_file`, the files in the build tree are only replaced as required.  This means that re-running CMake won't automatically make these files appear out-of-date to the build tool, hence avoiding an unnecessary recompilation.

```
set(ForeignLibName foreignLib-1.5.0_build123456)
set(ForeignLibRoot ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${ForeignLibName})
file(GLOB_RECURSE IncludeFiles RELATIVE ${ForeignLibRoot} ${ForeignLibRoot}/*)
foreach(IncludeFile ${IncludeFiles})
  configure_file(${ForeignLibRoot}/${IncludeFile}
                 ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${ForeignLibName}/foreignLib/${IncludeFile}
                 COPYONLY)
endforeach()

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${ForeignLibName})
```

This should allow you to do:

```
#include "foreignLib/include/lib.h"
```

When you update the foreign library, you'd have to ensure that you also updated the CMakeLists.txt so that CMake re-runs the next time you go to build.  Updating the CMakeLists.txt should only involve changing the single line `set(ForeignLibName ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the build process generate an include file at a well known location (later on called "boilerplate/foreignLib_lib.h") with the real include path.

your code file:

```
#include "boilerplate/foreignLib_lib.h"
```

boilerplate/foreignLib_lib.h:

```
#include "foreignLib-1.5.0_build123456/include/lib.h"
```

Comment: Though this one came to my mind first, my other answer is a lot more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Use CMake's `include_directories` statement or add an `-I` switch to the `*_CXX_FLAGS` to add the current foreignLib path to your include path.

Comment: That is actually just what I thought of, only that I still want to have a directory containing the files. If I add `foreignLib-1.5.0_build123456/` to my include path, I will reference the files with `#include "include/lib.h"` but I do not want that. The foreign lib include files should not potentially shadow other files from other foreign libs or my project.

Comment: Then you should add another directory level: `foreignLib-1.5.0_build123456/foreignLib/include/lib.h`

Comment: Yes, but the idea was to keep the `foreignLib-1.5.0_build123456` name from extracting the tarball of the foreign lib so I can just replace it next time. If there are additional steps that I have to take after unzipping, I might as well just change the directory name altogether, but that's not what I want to do.