# ESP32 IDF installation error (exit code=128)

Tags: esp32, aws-iot, arduino-esp8266, esp-idf

I am attempting the installation of ESP-IDF toolchain for windows with the installer from [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/windows-setup.html#get-started-windows-tools-installer)

However the installation fails with the exit-code=128.

Since I am a newbie I am not sure if I am missing something assuming the installer will take care of installation of all the dependencies

I am attaching the logs here for the reference

System Spec:
1.OS : windows 10
2. Processor : I7-8th Gen[image: Error Log]

Comment: You can maybe try to play with Git's `core.symlinks` flag. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664406/131929

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed git and python (I think you do if you tried to use the windows installer beforehand), you can try to install the toolchain from the terminal.

1. Open a CMD (Win+R, cmd, Intro)
2. Create a new folder (be aware that ESP-IDF does not like spaces in the path)
   2.1 `mkdir C:\esp`
   2.2 `cd C:\esp`
3. Clone the repository from git into the current directory with:
   `git clone -b v4.2 --recursive https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git .`  <= don't forget the ***.*** at the end
4. Run `install.bat`
5. Once installed, you can run in the folder you project lives `c:\esp\export.bat` which will set the environment variables for you to use `idf.py` tool.

Comment: Thanks! I t worked with some tweaks. After the mentioned steps there were python dependencies which were not satisfied, Cmake was not installed to which I ran the installer with the available repo downloaded  from the above steps. To which the things got smooth and working. Hence with your approach following with the installer I was able to run the "Hello-World "on the ESP32S development board. Surely this will be useful for the folks who will be getting the similar type of problem like mine

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install ESP-IDF on Windows and still having issues, try the latest installer with some pre-install verification.

You can download here: [IDF-Installer](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/esp-idf/?idf=4.4)

Alternatively, you can try this tool: [idf-env](https://github.com/espressif/idf-env)