# how to prevent softlinks while cloning the repo automatically using gitlab pipeline

Tags: git, powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

from [What happens when I clone a repository with symlinks on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662868/what-happens-when-i-clone-a-repository-with-symlinks-on-windows) post I got know that if core.symlinks is set to true, and we clone the repo, it prevents the softlinks on the windows while cloning the repo. I have tested this, it's working.

However, I have gitlab pipeline running on windows.I have a repo which has many symlinks.
When pipleine runs, it clone the repo, but it does not prevent the softlinks.

The machine, where I run the pipeline has, this variable set as true in the envirnoment as below, also deveoper mode is on.

```
C:\Users\asqa>git config --global --get core.symlinks
true
```

My question is, where do I set core.symlinks as true in .gitlab-ci.yml file so that the core.symlinks value is set before cloning of repo starts. I have tried below option but it's not working.
core.symlinks is always showing false as below:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
```

```
default:
  tags:
    - azebony
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - test
  - Run
variables:
  GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM: "true"

before_script:
  - git config core.symlinks true

test-job:
    stage: test
```

Could anybody help on this. I am stuck.