# How do I ignore a certain file type in a certain directory and its sub-directory in Git?

Tags: git

**How can I ignore a certain filetype only in one directory and its sub-directory?**

To explain what I mean imaging the following setup

- anotherdir/

  - seeme1.iml
- foldertoignore/

  - **ignoreme1.iml**
  - seeme3.txt
  - anotherignorefolder/

    - **ignoreme2.iml**
    - seeme4.txt
- seeme5.iml

I want to be able to do is tell git (using .gitignore file) to ignore *.iml but only under the directory *foldtertoignore*.

I was thinking this would work

```
foldertoignore/*.iml
```

But that only found *ignoreme1.iml* not *ignoreme2.iml*

I know how to tell it to ignore *.iml except for a specific directory. This is the reverse of that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

`.gitignore` rules are applied recursively from the containing directory. Simply create the file `foldertoignore/.gitignore` with `*.iml` as contents.

```
>>foldertoignore/.gitignore echo '*.iml'
git add foldertoignore/.gitignore
git commit -m 'Ignore .iml files in foldertoignore and its subfolders'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
/foldertoignore/**/*.iml
```

It may or may not work depending on fnmatch implementation in your OS I suppose. Alternative is:

```
*.iml
!/anotherdir/*.iml
!/*.iml
```

Comment: With msysgit on Windows, '`**`' doesn't seem to be applied recursively (as already seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971465/git-ignore-certain-files-contained-in-specific-folders/971523#971523, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991801/git-ignores-and-maven-targets/991873#991873, and explained in details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899875/git-add-not-working-with-png-files/2902126#2902126)

Comment: @Vonc - Didn't I say this may not work? And I don't suppose the OP mentioned msysgit?

Comment: @Vonc - Yeah knittl's answer is appropriate, but I like to manage a single gitignore from the root of the repo. So if the `**` works for OP, I would say go for it. Otherwise, go for knittl's answer

Comment: "I like to manage a single gitignore from the root of the repo": I completely agree. But I have never managed to do that on Windows, unfortunately. If the OP is not on Windows, he/she should know what answer to pick ;)