# How to remove all .svn directories from my application directories

Tags: linux, shell

One of the missions of an export tool I have in my application, is to clean all `.svn` directories from my application directory tree. I am looking for a recursive command in the Linux shell that will traverse the entire tree and delete the `.svn` files.

I am not using export, as this script will be used for some other file/directory names which are not related to SVN. I tried something like:

```
find . -name .svn | rm -fr
```

It didn't work...

Comment: Your command should work if you use 'xargs rm -rf'

Comment: You might also want to modify the delete command "rm -rfi" just to make sure you are positive you want to delete the directories.

Comment: Don't use xargs though.. you'll have trouble with directories that have spaces in them etc. Use find as described below.

Answer (score 447, accepted):

Try this:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Before running a command like that, I often like to run this first:

```
find . -name .svn -exec ls '{}' \;
```

Comment: You may need to put {} into single quote if there may be space or such characters in directories:

`find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

Comment: This test works better in my bash : `find . -name .svn -exec echo {} \;`

Comment: Running echo / ls first is the 'pro' touch to this answer. Any fool can wreck a system.

Comment: why is using echo better?

Comment: @BillR Because echo will list the directories to removed, where as ls will list their contents.

Comment: what does the `{} \;` do?

Comment: This answer breaks if done in a script, like a makefile. I guess because **find: ./assets/Assets/res/dictionary/3x: No such file or directory** etc is output for me. (did a find on 3x)

Comment: can you explain what each of those commands do? I ran the second one and files removed. It rejected to run the first one later?! I thought I have to run both! Is that what should happen?

Comment: By running the second command including `ls`, I get `entries  prop-base  props  text-base  tmp` output...

Comment: @Rasoul try @Fedir solution: `find . -name .svn -exec echo {} \;`

Comment: `man find`(1) shows a suitable example to detects whether some SCM administrative directories:
    `find repo/ -exec test -d {}/.svn \; -or -exec test -d {}/.git \; -or -exec test -d {}/CVS \; -print -prune`

Answer (score 53):

What you wrote sends a list of newline separated file names (and paths) to `rm`, but rm doesn't know what to do with that input.  It's only expecting command line parameters.

`xargs` takes input, usually separated by newlines, and places them on the command line, so adding xargs makes what you had work:

```
find . -name .svn | xargs rm -fr
```

`xargs` is intelligent enough that it will only pass as many arguments to `rm` as it can accept.  Thus, if you had a million files, it might run `rm` 1,000,000/65,000 times (if your shell could accept 65,002 arguments on the command line {65k files + 1 for rm + 1 for -fr}).

As persons have adeptly pointed out, the following also work:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
find . -depth -name .svn -exec rm -fr {} \;
find . -type d -name .svn -print0|xargs -0 rm -rf
```

The first two `-exec` forms both call `rm` for each folder being deleted, so if you had 1,000,000 folders, `rm` would be invoked 1,000,000 times.  This is certainly less than ideal.  Newer implementations of `rm` allow you to conclude the command with a `+` indicating that `rm` will accept as many arguments as possible:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} +
```

The last find/xargs version uses print0, which makes find generate output that uses `\0` as a terminator rather than a newline.  Since POSIX systems allow any character but `\0` in the filename, this is truly the safest way to make sure that the arguments are correctly passed to `rm` or the application being executed.

In addition, there's a `-execdir` that will execute `rm` from the directory in which the file was found, rather than at the base directory and a `-depth` that will start depth first.

Answer (score 31):

No need for pipes, xargs, exec, or anything:

```
find . -name .svn -delete
```

**Edit:** Just kidding, evidently `-delete` calls `unlinkat()` under the hood, so it behaves like `unlink` or `rmdir` and will refuse to operate on directories containing files.

Comment: One problem, `-delete` won't touch a directory if it contains files.

Comment: There's no `-force` or recursive flag for `-delete` predicate, so this answer is useless. Thus, it's back to `|xargs rm -rf`, which is less ugly to type then `-exec` with its ugly placeholders and semicolon: `-exec rm -rf '{}' \;`.

Answer (score 14):

There are already many answers provided for deleting the .svn-directory. But I want to add, that you can avoid these directories from the beginning, if you do an export instead of a checkout:

```
svn export <url>
```

Comment: +1, there's no need to redo this when it's already built-in to svn.

Comment: Only issue I see with this approach is if you want to retain unversioned files in the export. From the svn docs, "All local changes will be preserved, but files not under version control will not be copied."

Comment: @raidfive: Usually I prefer to have all relevant files under version-control, even used libraries, so that the project works out of the box. Unversioned files in this setup are compiled binaries, that are remade by a goal in the buildfile. But you are right, if your project relies on files not under version control, an export wouldn't work.

Comment: but...I needed a more generalistic answer. The .svn was just the most common example, I noted that in the question.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't like to see a lot of

```
find: `./.svn': No such file or directory
```

warnings, then use the `-depth` switch:

```
find . -depth -name .svn -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

Answer (score 11):

In Windows, you can use the following registry script to add "Delete SVN Folders" to your right click context menu. Run it on any directory containing those pesky files.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN]
@="Delete SVN Folders"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN\command]
@="cmd.exe /c \"TITLE Removing SVN Folders in %1 && COLOR 9A && FOR /r \"%1\" %%f IN (.svn) DO RD /s /q \"%%f\" \""
```

Comment: Neat trick. Not helpful for the OP, but +1 because I was impressed!

Comment: this is awesome. thanks. i know this is super old, but whatever. i love it anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You almost had it. If you want to pass the output of a command as parameters to another one, you'll need to use xargs. Adding `-print0` makes sure the script can handle paths with whitespace:

```
find . -type d -name .svn -print0|xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: for some reson what worked eventualy was find . -name .svn |xargs rm -rf  
Your version gave me the direction though, thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name .svn |xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 4):

As an important issue, when you want to utilize *shell* to delete .svn folders You need **-depth** argument to prevent find command entering the directory that was just deleted and showing error messages like e.g.

```
"find: ./.svn: No such file or directory"
```

As a result, You can use find command like below:

```
cd [dir_to_delete_svn_folders]
find . -depth -name .svn -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for and should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Read more about the find command at [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-find.html).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you want to export a copy without modifying the working copy, you can use rsync:

```
rsync -a --exclude .svn path/to/working/copy path/to/export
```

Comment: Or use svn export /path/to/repository, which essentially does the same thing.

Comment: The author specifically said he didn't want to use svn; perhaps his target environment doesn't have svn installed.