# How to fix corrupt local Subversion working copy?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I usually use git and know little beyond the basics of Subversion, so please be gentle.

I'm using TortoiseSVN on Windows 7. The SVN client recently announced it needed to upgrade, so I did that. All files lost their source control icons, and a new menu item appeared in Explorer prompting me to upgrade my repository working copy to v1.7. I did that and see the error attached.

I've searched for the file it mentions, it does not exist in my local repository. I seem unable to do a Clean as the menu item doesn't exist as the TortoiseSVN menu has reduced to bare basics: Repo browser (which opens an empty dialog), Properties, Settings, Help, About.

What complicates matters is I have local changes, so I can't trash my local copy and update my local from the repository.

How can I fix my broken local copy, whilst maintaining my local changes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the TortoiseSVN menu options available in my local copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working copy needs to be updated which means in other words simply make a fresh checkout with the new installed TortoiseSVN client (1.7.x) instead of using the old working copy. The repository doesn't need an update (you can if you like).
The simplest solution is to create a fresh checkout into a different directory and then copy your changes to that new working copy and do a commit from there. Why did you do an update without prior checking in all recent changes?

Comment: In theory I could do this, but I do not have records of what has changed so merging could be painful. I'm loathed to copy the whole source tree over the newly checked out version - not least because I'd have to delete all the snv folders first.

Comment: "Why did you do an update without prior checking in all recent changes?" I trued TortoiseSVN not to completely destroy my local copy. Obviously with hindsight I wish I had.

Comment: Not in theory. You can exactly do it in that way. Cause you ignored the recommendations for the working copy / client update http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng. So you have to do do the work once. There is no other way around that. Sorry.

Comment: fyi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294590/how-to-remove-all-svn-directories-from-my-application-directories

Answer (score 2):

1. Cleanup exist, but - only inside WC, which, while you don't update WC, is not your case
2. Downgraded TSVN can Cleanup, after it you *can* upgrade TSVN to 1.7 (and update WC after it), but *can do not do it* and use 1.6 client

Answer (score 1):

The message says:

> Try a 'Cleanup'. If that doesn't work you need to do a fresh checkout.

So what I would do is try a cleanup. And if it didn't work, I would do a fresh checkout.

These two commands are in the TortoiseSVN context menu. And there's also a Help menu if yo don't understand how these commands work.

If you end up doing a fresh checkout, you can always use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare your old, corrupted working copy with the new one, and reapply your local changes to your fresh working copy.

Comment: I said in my original question that there is no Clean context menu option. It's no longer there. I'm glad I use git, this Tortoise client is awful.

Comment: @OllieC, you can bring those menu items back from settings. Also note that those options only show if you are inside a SVN local copy. mine shows 25 items.