# Why is Git not staging some "modified" folders for an initial commit?

Tags: git, erpnext

I have received code for a modified older version of [ERPNext](https://erpnext.com/) from a backup tarball, and I want to add this code into a local Git repository on my Ubuntu laptop so I can keep track of changes until my employer can host a remote repository. Assuming that the backup was already extracted in `~/backup/erpnext/`, I am trying to set up my Git repository for an initial commit like this:

```
cd ~
mkdir erpnext
cd erpnext
cp -r ~/backup/erpnext/* ./
git init
git add *
```

This, I thought, should add all of the files and folders in the backup to the `~/erpnext` directory and stage them all for an initial commit. However, just to make sure it all works as expected, I ran `git status` before making a commit and was greeted with this output:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   app
    new file:   conf.py
    new file:   conf.pyc
    new file:   erpnext-backup.log
    new file:   erpnext-sch.log
    new file:   lib
    new file:   public/app
    new file:   public/app.html
    new file:   public/css/all-app.css
    new file:   public/css/all-web.css
    new file:   public/js/all-app.min.js
    new file:   public/js/all-web.min.js
    new file:   public/js/editor.min.js
    new file:   public/js/slickgrid.min.js
    new file:   public/lib
    new file:   scheduler.lock

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   app (modified content, untracked content)
    modified:   lib (modified content, untracked content)
```

What took me by surprise was that `app` and `lib` (which are both folders) were marked as having modified contents and were not staged for committing. I tried running `git add --force` on `*`, `app` and `lib`, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I don't want to commit my code and have these folders excluded from the repository. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are `app` and `lib` *folders* or are they *submodules*?

Comment: do the `app/` folder and the `lib/` folder by any chances contain a `.git/` directory?

Comment: @EdwardThomson They should just be folders, AFAIK. This is all one self-contained project, so I wouldn't expect there to be any [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) within it.

Comment: @umläute Now that I take a look at it in my file manager, yes, the `.git/` directory is present, as well as a `.gitignore`. Should these be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove any `.git/` directories in those sub-folders.
they might confuse `git` (see `git submodules` for more information).

(btw, you can leave any `.gitignore` files, as they will hopefully help ignoring temporary files specific to these folders).

here's a handy command to remove all `.git` directories in any subdirectory of `~/erpnext` (but not `~/erpnext/.git`):

```
 find ~/erpnext/ -depth -mindepth 2 -type d -name .git -exec rm -rf \{\} \;
```

alternatively, if your upstream project is already a git repository (with submodules), you might just want to keep the original history, by continuing to work on the original VCS:

```
cd ~
rm -rf erpnext
cp -r ~/backup/erpnext .
cd erpnext
git log
```

Comment: Thank you very much! By the ways, to anyone else reading this: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1294590/3775798) useful for getting rid of those `.git/` directories.

Comment: i added a (slightly different) command to remove those directories to the answer.