# Folder in Git listed as file with no extension

Tags: .net, reactjs, git, push, commit

I have a problem with staging changes in a folder.
It is a React project next to .NET project - a folder basically.
Git views it as a file without extension and prevents from staging changes, therefore I cannot commit changes.

What happened? Why is it listed that way and how can I fix it?

[image: Unstaged file is actually a folder, but is listed as file with no extension.]

Comment: check this if it helps to you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412858/why-is-git-not-staging-some-modified-folders-for-an-initial-commit

Answer (score 0):

That client_app folder has a `.git` in it, which makes client_app a nested git repository for its parent main repository.

A nested Git repository is treated as a [**gitlink**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#Documentation/git-fast-import.txt-Inlinedataformat)

> 160000: A gitlink, SHA-1 of the object refers to a commit in another repository. Git links can only be specified by SHA or through a commit mark.
> They are used to implement submodules.

Unless you main repository has a `.gitmodules` file, you cannot directly stage content in client_app.
Or, as commented, you would need to delete its `.git/` subfolder in order for the main repository to see client_app as a regular folder.