# Is there a way to delete all directories with the same name?

Tags: winscp

Long story short, I am trying to delete all .svn folders within my site.

I have tried to use a file mask: `*/.svn/*`

Search in: `/data/www/content/`

But it's returning files named entries. It shows me all the directories the entries file is showing in which is helpful, but then I need to go to that directory and delete them one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small help popup says that masks ending in `/` will find folders, so I tried `.svn/` and it does find that in the current folder. But it does not search recursively in sub folders.

Since you are using WinSCP you [probably](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/do-you-need-a-shell-for-scp) have Bash or SSH access too, you could try one of the scripts mentioned in this Stackoverflow question: [How to remove all .svn directories from my application directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294590/how-to-remove-all-svn-directories-from-my-application-directories)

Comment: Thanks for finding that for me. The answer from that question worked: find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this task repeatedly, you can write a [PowerShell script using WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

There's already a [Search recursively for text in remote directory](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_recursive_search_text) example provided.

Your task is not that different. Instead of downloading (`$session.GetFiles`) and grepping a matching file, you delete it ([`$session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles)).