# git excludes vs ignores

Tags: git, gitignore, git-tower

I use [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) for using Git in Mac.
The settings in Tower has Ignores section which creates the .gitignore, but it has another section named "Excludes". And it seems like that one can use excludes with "# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude".

[image: Tower screenshot]

What Excludes is for? Why one needs excludes when gitignore is available?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's a list of files that are not in `.gitignore` (which can be versioned), but which you want to exclude on your machine's copy of the repo.

From [the docs](http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore):

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do
>   not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary
>   files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user's
>   workflow) should go into the $GIT_DIR/info/exclude file.

Note that .git/info/exclude can not be versioned because it's in the .git directory.

Comment: So, it's basically a `.gitignore` that doesn't get revisioned? For if I want to ignore some files, but don't want others to ignore them?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, exactly.  For example, if you're the only one on your team who uses a particular IDE, you can exclude files it creates.