# How to include .svn directory in the file .gitignore ? (all the directories whose name contains dot)

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exclude .svn folders within git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821895/exclude-svn-folders-within-git)

How to include .svn directory in the file .gitignore ? (all the directories whose name contains dot or begins with dot)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha have the different purpose, he want to use git in client  with subversion server, but I want to booth use git and svn in client.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question [Exclude .svn folders within git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821895/exclude-svn-folders-within-git):

> I think you want to use a .gitignore file in your top-level directory. This will work if you put ".svn/entries" on a line in that file. You might just put ".svn" instead of ".svn/entries" as well.

Comment: I´ve just tested it in one of my old subversion repositories and adding a line ".svn" in .gitignore was enough. See the comments of the question I pointed to to see what to do if your .svn folders already are inside your git repo.

Comment: If I do 'git rm -r .svn', the directory '.svn' is deleted, the folder is no under the version control subversion ?

Comment: Well, if you delete all the .svn folders in your project, then you can say that you are not under subversion anymore.

Comment: So, assume that there is a command 'untracked' instead of 'rm', there will be OK……