# Are there any bad side effects by ignoring .gitignore?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

Example .gitignore:

```
.gitignore
.DS_Store 
.project
.pydevproject
...
```

Is it bad to add .gitignore?  I don't need it tracked and I don't like clutter.

An acceptable answer is, "You are being a whiny brat who gets annoyed at things that shouldn't ruffle your feathers.  So knock it off your wasting our time."

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You are being a whiny brat who gets annoyed at things that shouldn't ruffle your feathers. So knock it off your wasting our time.", @NaZer

[Ignore the .gitignore file itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767147/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-gitignore)

The accepted answer explains why it should be on version control.

Comment: Thanks for the link helps with rationale

Answer (score 1):

The `.gitignore` file is intended to be shared with all copies of the repo.  That's why it's in the working tree instead of inside the `.git` directory.  Put files into `.git/info/exclude` if you only want to ignore things in your copy.  For example, if you use an editor no one else at your company does, or you're using a second VCS from within the same working tree.