# Git ignore local changes to portions of tracked files

Tags: git

Specifically, I maintain a git repository of my dotfiles. I recently started working on a new machine and cloned my repository on the same.

Now, I wish to make some changes to my dotfiles which are specific to this system only. These changes I wish to ignore in my repository.

Other changes that I make, should continue to be tracked and committed.

For example, in my .gitconfig, I have a setting as:

```
[push]
   default = simple
```

Now, on my new machine, the version of git being used it very old. It still not not support the setting `simple` for push. So, I'd like to change this, but only locally.

However, if I make any other changes to my .gitconfig, I'd like to keep track of those. Anyway I can achieve this?

EDIT:
I know of `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. The problem with it is that git will no longer track my file at all, until I reverse it. And then, it will track all changes.
I wish to ignore certain changes and track the rest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Committing Machine Specific Configuration Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396617/committing-machine-specific-configuration-files)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe there's a specific command that will 'untrack' certain changes to a file.  However, there's no reason that you couldn't create a local branch into which you pull changes from your remotes, but never send any changes back.

Comment: Duh! That's exactly what I need! Sending those changes to a branch! Thanks! I've been over-engineering this situation.

Comment: Please explain. If you have a local branch that you only pull changes in, but never send any changes back, how can you transfer the changes you made in that local branch to the main code base?

Answer (score 191):

Try using this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged FILENAME_TO_IGNORE
```

To reverse it (if you ever want to commit changes to it), use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged
```

**UPDATE**:

Here's how to list **'assume unchanged'** files under current directory:

```
git ls-files -v | grep -E "^[a-z]"
```

As the `-v` option will use lowercase letters for 'assume unchanged' files.

Comment: The problem with `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is that it will no longer track my file at all, until I reverse it. And then, it will track all changes.

I wish to ignore certain changes and track the rest.

Comment: However this was exactly what I needed in my situation! A file my teammates use slows down the test suite by dozens of seconds, so I delete it all the time... but the fact that it's gone pollutes my git session. Not anymore though!

Comment: For the people who got here and thought "`--assume-unchanged` is perfect as I do want to ignore all changes to the file" try "--skip-worktree" instead.

Comment: `--skip-worktree` explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree

Comment: The problem I have with this is that `git checkout` still won't let me change branches if the changes to that file cause a conflict :T

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel You can try "git stash" before changing branches.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative solution to your specific problem. Place machine-config configuration in a `~/.gitconfig.local` file, and then put the following in your version-controlled `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[include]
    path = ~/.gitconfig.local
```

This will tell Git to treat anything it finds in `~/.gitconfig.local` as if it were in `~/.gitconfig`. Yes, you can override settings. No, it does not require the file to exist (Git will silently ignore the setting if there is no `~/.gitconfig.local`).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig) for more information about `[include]`.

I follow this strategy in my configurations for Emacs, Zsh, Git, Tmux, etc., so that they are customizable without the need to modify version-controlled files. To accomplish this, I have `init.local.el`, `.zshrc.local`, `.gitconfig.local`, `.tmux.local.conf`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Peter you can keep those machine specific changes in a branch. Obviously you will have to be careful to strictly separate changes to those machine specific files from the "mainline". There are 2 ways for doing this:

1. Keep rebasing the branch whenever you change the mainline (this would be my preference)
2. Keep merging mainline changes into the branch (but obviously *never* merge in the other direction)