# Ignoring a file tracked in Bitbucket

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a config file 'config.js' in my Bitbuckt repo with a specific configuration that I don't want to change.

I need to change this file to work locally, but I don't want to send this changes to my repo.

I already put this file in .gitignore but, every time I push my project, the file in Bitbuckt is replaced with local config.

How can I fix this?

PS: I tried to use $ git rm --cached config.js, but this deletes the file in Bitbuckt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git ignore local changes to tracked files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756531/git-ignore-local-changes-to-tracked-files)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally

Comment: Thanks @TheReaper, this post answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was ignore changes to the file using the command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file_name
```

And just an observation, the undo command is:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file_name
```

**UPDATED:**

I found a problem with this solution.
When I try to change branch, I got an error (Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:)

How can I solve it?