# Ignore local changes and switch branch

Tags: git

I have an `App.config` file that is modified locally but I do not want to commit the changes:

```
On branch test
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/test'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Test/App.config

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So according to [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21756612/465056) I executed the following command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged Test/App.config
```

So that `git status` gives the following output:

```
On branch test
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/test'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Everything seems fine, **except when I try to switch to another branch**. The output when I executed `git checkout test2`:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Test/App.Config
```

My question is, is there any way to switch branch while keeping the locally modified file? Or is `git stash` the only solution?

Comment: If you want to keep the file unmodified when switching branches, absolutely use `git stash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git assumes that the file is unchanged so it will not show it in the git status.

As a good scm tool git must ensure that you do not accedentially loose changes. If you switch to the other branch the file `Test/App.config` would be overridden. That's why git refuses the checkout and tells you that there are changes.

I would suggest to not use `assume unchanged`. Instead stash the local changes, checkout another branch and pop the stash.

In order to fix your repo you should do

```
 git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Test/App.config
 git stash
 git checkout test2
 git stash pop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the file `App.config` **has been modified in the other branch**.

Because the file has been modified, you MUST tell git how to handle the issue (commit or stash).

Maybe using a git ignore could be an other solution for you ?

Comment: Actually `App.config` does not exist in the other branch, but is it related to the reason why I am getting the error?

Comment: @rexcfnghk Yes, if App.config existed in the other branch, you could've switched