# GIT error on merge after fetching from remote origin on files I want to keep intact locally

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore, git-pull

There are files in local project, I want to keep untouched - some configs with directives neccessary only for local development. I also do not want them to go to remote origin as it will break the app.

I've put corresponding entries to .gitignore, which I also do not want either to share nor accept changes into it.
I even did `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, so changes in mentioned files not tracked and not shown on "git status".
But when "pulling" from remote origin (or explicitly make merge after fetch) I get

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:     
    .gitignore  
    app/core/config.js

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Due to the fact my staging area is empty there is nothing to commit or stash.
Which is proper set up for the case when I have files not to be merged?

Comment: Do some of the files already exist in the remote repository? Git usually only warns you if it really *would* overwrite some files.

Comment: Yes, there is a large project there with long commit history.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your local `.gitignore` file: you have a local one, but there is also one in the remote repository. Upon merging, your local .gitignore would be overwritten. Since there exists a `.gitignore` file, you should just add the contents of your local `.gitignore` to the one in the remote repository.

Also, since `app/core/config.js` is also mentioned here, I suspect that it's not listed in your `.gitignore` although it should be.

Comment: Yes both .gitignore and app/core/config.js entries are already in .gitignore.

Comment: But as I`ve already realized .gitignore has no power after cloning, so maybe there is a possibility to create it before cloning. Need to try it before making conclusion. Besides I wouldn`t change remote  .gitignore file.

Comment: You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767213/7598462) that suggest the use of `.git/info/exclude` to ignore files locally. The `.gitignore` file is intended to be shared across the repository.