# Need to have two gitignore files in single project

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to have two .gitignore files.

I would like to have two `.gitignore` files for my project. One is already committed to the repo. I do not want to change that file & at the same time I want to ignore some other files (We are a big team & strict code review practice stops us from committing `.gitignore` files to repo)

Can I point my repo to two *ignore files*? Or can I have a local `gitignore` file & a `global gitignore` file?

Can we even replicate this in some sandbox & see a live example online.

Comment: You can add the extra ignored patterns to `.git/info/exclude`. It affects the current repository only and won't be added or committed.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/767213/6671004

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make Git ignore files without using .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653454/how-do-you-make-git-ignore-files-without-using-gitignore)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+local+.gitignore

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can have a global `.gitignore`.
You can do this by using the following commands.

`touch ~/.gitignore`

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore`

This will set your global .gitignore.

See: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore/2.22.0 for more details.

Edit: As suggested by @ElpieKay, if you want a project specific ignore on top of the .gitignore you can add them .git/info/exclude.

Comment: Can we add a file to ignore list (through .git/info/exclude)  if it is already checked in to repo?

Comment: @ahmed I would imagine no - just like if file were in .gitignore proper. First remove it from git version control with `git rm yourFile` then add `yourFile` to `.git/info/exclude`.