# .gitignore file itself is not being ignored after an edit

Tags: git, gitignore

Prior to editing the .gitignore file in a project the following files were displayed when the status was queried:
[image]

Wanting to ignore the multiple versions of sandbox Vue files, this was added to the project's .gitignore file at the bottom:

```
# app files
/src/modules/admin/views/sandbox*.vue
```

Now when the status is queried the following is displayed:
[image]

Why is `../.gitignore` being displayed now?  What should be changed so that file is not displayed?

Comment: Your filenames solved my multiple years' low blood pressure...

Comment: Check out [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1753070/5958455). Basically you'd put ignore lines *specific to your local clone* inside `.git/info/exclude`, which will not be tracked like `.gitignore`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I stop .gitignore from appearing in the list of untracked files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767147/how-can-i-stop-gitignore-from-appearing-in-the-list-of-untracked-files)

Comment: @Dev-vruper Yes, that thread is helpful.

Comment: Some things aren't intuitive at first, but once you understand them, they become funny. (I hope even OP would agree.) To summarize what happened here: Q: Why is my file showing as modified? A: Because you modified it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `.gitignore` is a tracked file.... so you changed it, so it shows up as changed. This would be the expected result... and it makes sense. Do you want to *ignore* .gitignore? This is not quite a good idea because by tracking it, everyone gets to *ignore* the same things in the project. Now, if you would like to be **the only person** in the project to be ignoring the files that you started the question from, you might have to consider adding that to `.git/info/exclude` so that it's only *on you* and no one else.