# Exceptions in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

How can I add an exception to .gitignore, like "ignore all the .dll files **BUT** myfile.dll"?

Answer (score 371, accepted):

Use `!` to negate the pattern:

```
*.dll
!myfile.dll
```

Answer (score 240):

If you want to ignore whole folder, except some specific files, then write:

```
MyFolder/*
!MyFolder/CoolFile.txt
```

This **won't** work:

```
MyFolder/
!MyFolder/CoolFile.txt
```

Comment: Note that this extends to subdirectories as well. For example, this will work:

`MyFolder/sub/*

!MyFolder/sub/file.txt`

But this won't:
`MyFolder/*

!MyFolder/sub/file.txt`

Comment: The reason - " It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. " [https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore]

Comment: So "for performance reasons" I have to manually enter 21 different subfolders that have the same name and were previously ignored by a single line, just so I can exclude one file.  

Comment: @endolith, have you found a better way to do it?

Answer (score 49):

You can also ignore **folders** like

```
!src/main/resources/archetype-resources/**/*
```

you can also ignore **nested folder with patterns** like

```
!**/src/test/resources/**/*
```

For quick creation of .gitignore file try [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io)

Comment: you mean "ignore ignoring them", so they will be included in the source repository ;-)

Answer (score 17):

I did this because I have a folder called `/modules` that I want to ignore, except everything in the `/modules/custom` folder. This worked for me. Now my custom modules will get synced to GitHub.

```
/modules/*
!/modules/custom/
```

Comment: This is the only method that actually worked for me.

Comment: OMG thank you, exactly what I was trying to do and amazing how many garbage answers I had to sift through to find this.

Answer (score 14):

You can have several `.gitignore` files working together in a hierarchical manner to achieve your goal.
At the root level you may have:

*root*

```
*.dll
```

inside the folder having the `myfile.dll` you can add another `.gitignore` file like so:

*root/lib/folderwithMyFiledll*

```
!myfile.dll
```

more info [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt". It is possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded if certain conditions are met. See section NOTES for detail.

Comment: The doc snippet you pasted seems out of date. The site currently states that you can't re-include files under parent directories.