# git ignore exception

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a gitignore file that makes git ignore `*.dll` files, and that is actually the behavior I want. However, if I want an exception ( i.e. to be able to commit `foo.dll`), how can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exceptions in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415873/exceptions-in-gitignore)

Comment: fwiw, the granddaddy of duplicate answers on this topic--one that you should look over--would probably be [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files) - very regular activity and several good answers. I'm a particular fan of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932318/5440638), which seems clear and thorough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Answer (score 625, accepted):

Use:

```
*.dll    #Exclude all dlls
!foo.dll #Except for foo.dll
```

From [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources.

Comment: See also answer form @Matiss Jurgelis - it's important addition

Comment: Can I add the exception to my project's gitignore and not my global gitignore? For example, if I wanted to include all DLLs in a directory? My gitignore_global has `*.dll` in it, and my project's gitignore has `!Libs/*.dll` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @jkinz, you should try `!Libs/**/*.dll`.

Comment: @RosbergLinhares Or `!**/Libs/*.dll`, depending on the folder structure.

Comment: Thanks, but on a mac adding the comment on the same line as the `!foo.dll` did invalidate the command. If I add the comment on a separate row it works.

Comment: @Giacomo I had the same on Windows, `#` should be avoided.

Answer (score 389):

Git ignores folders if you write:

```
/js
```

but it can't add exceptions if you do:
`!/js/jquery` or `!/js/jquery/` or `!/js/jquery/*`

You must write:

```
/js/*
```

and only then you can except subfolders like this

```
!/js/jquery
```

Comment: However looks like you can't add nested folders, e.g. `!/js/jquery/xyzlib` will not be ignored...

Comment: As @Ignorant says, the folder you "except" from the ignore rule, must be at the same location as the "*"

Comment: so `/js/*`, `!/js/jquery`, `/js/jquery/*`, `!/js/jquery/xyzlib`? Feels like a rather funny way to do it...

Comment: With git 2.21 not any of those solutions work - how can they ignore this problem!!!???

Comment: @Ignorant for nested subfolders see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72380673/2321594

Answer (score 68):

You can simply `git add -f path/to/foo.dll`.

`.gitignore` ignores only files for usual tracking and stuff like `git add .`

Comment: Just for more details, the `-f` tells git to force the adding of this file in the repo since it might ignore it first because of your `.gitignore`

Comment: Which is great if you only have one file, less useful if you need a pattern

Comment: Good to know. But still better manage all the rules in the .gitignore than not knowing some rules are defined else where, especially in a team context

Answer (score 25):

To exclude everything in a directory, but some sub-directories, do the following:

```
wp-content/*
!wp-content/plugins/
!wp-content/themes/
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/444295

Comment: But what is about one file in subdirectory? ( dir1/ , !dir1/dir2/some_file )

Answer (score 15):

Just add `!` before an exclusion rule.

According to the [gitignore man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Patterns have the following format:
>
> ...
>
> - An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources.

Answer (score 8):

For **Nested Folders**, I came up with a solution based on [Matiss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731573/2321594).

Let's say I want to ignore everything in `build/` directory (which is in `/app`). So I do:

```
build/*
```

However, if I want to exclude `build/outputs/bundle/release` subfolder, I need to play some hide and seek!

```
/app/build/*
!/app/build/outputs
/app/build/outputs/*
!/app/build/outputs/bundle
/app/build/outputs/bundle/*
!/app/build/outputs/bundle/release
```

#### Important Notes:

- All the paths should start with `/` and be relative to the `.gitignore`
- You have to do it one subfolder at a time.  You can see in VS Code (for instance) what it includes and what not at every step.

Answer (score 5):

`!foo.dll` in .gitignore, or (every time!) `git add -f foo.dll`

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with Visual Studio and your .dll happens to be in a `bin` folder, then you'll need to add an exception for the particular bin folder itself, before you can add the exception for the .dll file. E.g.

```
!SourceCode/Solution/Project/bin
!SourceCode/Solution/Project/bin/My.dll
```

This is because the default Visual Studio `.gitignore` file includes an ignore pattern for `[Bbin]/`

This pattern is zapping all bin folders (and consequently their contents), which makes any attempt to include the contents redundant (since the folder itself is already ignored).

I was able to find why my file wasn't being excepted by running

```
git check-ignore -v -- SourceCode/Solution/Project/bin/My.dll
```

from a Git Bash window. This returned the `[Bbin]/` pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The solution depends on the relation between the git ignore rule and the exception rule:

1. Files/Files at the same level: use the [@Skilldrick solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception/3203249#3203249).
2. Folders/Subfolders: use the [@Matiss Jurgelis solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception/14731573#14731573).
3. Files/Files in different levels or Files/Subfolders: you can do this:

   ```
   *.suo
   *.user
   *.userosscache
   *.sln.docstates

   # ...

   # Exceptions for entire subfolders
   !SetupFiles/elasticsearch-5.0.0/**/*
   !SetupFiles/filebeat-5.0.0-windows-x86_64/**/*

   # Exceptions for files in different levels
   !SetupFiles/kibana-5.0.0-windows-x86/**/*.suo
   !SetupFiles/logstash-5.0.0/**/*.suo
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it, with a README.md file in each directory:

```
/data/*
!/data/README.md

!/data/input/
/data/input/*
!/data/input/README.md

!/data/output/
/data/output/*
!/data/output/README.md
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Git 2.7.0 Git will take exceptions into account. From the official release notes:

> - Allow a later "!/abc/def" to override an earlier "/abc" that
>   appears in the same .gitignore file to make it easier to express
>   "everything in /abc directory is ignored, except for ...".

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt

edit: apparently this doesn't work any more since Git 2.8.0

Comment: does this work for anyone? doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53753201/125507 this was removed

Comment: It's not working for me on version 2.25.1. Do you happen to know a way around it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a directory and want to ignore everything with the exception of some files (e.g. `*.py` files), you can do:

```
sub-dir/**/*.*
!sub-dir/**/*.py
```

Comment: This should be higher up. Also, you can explicitly set the deapth (not sure why you would) like so "folder/*/*" and "!folder/*/file"