# Un-ignore all files in global .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore, ignore

After looking at [git ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception), I realized that one can ignore files in a repository from a global .gitignore file.

Is there any way that you can override all rules from the global .gitignore file, so that the repository will have everything in it and nothing ignored? (besides un-ignoring every file individually)

Comment: you mean in a subfolder? something like !subfolder/*.dll ?

Comment: It seems to me you could "override all rules from the global .gitignore" simply by removing the `.gitignore`. Perhaps that's not quite what you want, though...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore` in the repo folder with one rule:

```
!*
```

This forgets the rules (with `!`) of all of the files (`*`) in the main `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 2):

You can.

Create you own `.gitignore` file with appropriate rules and put into directory in where it shall apply. The rules will be applicable for a directory with local `.gitignore` and its subdirs.