# Ignore a global gitignore rule for specific repository

Tags: git

I have a global `.gitignore` file at my home directory. For a certain repository, I want one ignore pattern specified in my global `.gitignore` to be ignored because files with that pattern are necessary to be tracked in this repository. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your local repository add a .gitignore file that negates the rule from your global .gitignore.

For example:

global .gitignore

```
*.foo
```

repos .gitignore

```
!*.foo
```

You are basically doing the same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3203228/498699).  Just in two different files.