# Directory commit if part of name matches ignored file ext

Tags: git, gitignore

I got the following situation: in .gitignore I have the following

#Visual Studio files
...
*.lib
...
Skipping *.lib files is good.

In addition I have lots of Library directories as part of this repo with names like aaa.bbb.ccc.lib which I'd like to commit. 
Have tons of those projects which are very similar so I'm pretty much reusing the same .gitignore. 
What is the proper way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an exception rule after the general .lib exclusion rule.  See [git ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception) for examples.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this exception rule should probably look like `!*.lib/`