# Preserve uploaded folder contents after placing local directory in .gitignore

Tags: git, laravel, heroku

I am maintaining a Laravel project on heroku using git.

There is a folder **public/assets/uploads** which has jpg image files in it.
So I have added **public/assets/uploads/*.jpg** to .gitignore.

As expected, any new files created in this folder is ignored while doing *git push*, but unexpectedly, it also removes my already existing .jpg files on the server.

I don't want any one to one correspondence between my local uploads/ folder and the uploads/ folder on the server. Local changes should stay local and online changes should stay online. I have been hittig my head for a long time searching on google and haven't found any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git ignore exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception)

Comment: When a file is committed to a git repo, it is there until you explicitly remove it. Adding a .gitignore rule that matches the file won't remove the file from the repo.

Comment: Also note that ignore rules affect the behavior of `git add`, not `git push`.

Comment: There was a different problem than I thought. Actually when my project dyno will restart on heroku, any changes made online will be lost. So what @Code-Apprentice said is true