# Subfolder's .gitignore should override

Tags: gitignore

I have a project which tree structure looks like this:

`+ /Root
- .gitignore
+ - - /Folder A
- - - .gitignore      <--- this fellow
+ - - - /bin
- - - - - fileA
+ - - - - fileB
+ - - - /Folder AA
+ - - /FolderB
+ - - - /bin
...`

The `.gitignore` in the root-folder has a lot of rules, among them is to ignore all `/bin`-folders.
However, in my `FolderA` I would like everything to stay as it is - all the way down in **that** folder.
`FolderB/bin` on the other hand should be ignored.

I know this is possible by adding another `.gitignore` in `FolderA`, and let this override the root folder's `.gitignore`. But I can't remember how.

What should I write in `FolderA/.gitignore`?

**Edit**:
In other words: *"`FolderA` is a sacred folder, and must have all files in it stay in it, disregarding what any other `.gitignore`-files must say"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception)

Comment: @SimonKuang No, I need a rule that states "this entire subfolder must not be excluded, at all, in any way, disregarding what any other ``.gitignore``-file say".

Comment: Does `!bin/*` not work?

Comment: It does, but then ``bin/aFolder/bin``does not, and I have so many from this third-party dependency. So I need *everything* excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

In the `.gitignore` file added in the folder needed to be excluded, the following line is added as the only line:

`!*/`

Answer (score 1):

Override the root `.gitignore` in `/FolderA/.gitignore` using the include syntax:

```
!file_that_should_not_be_ignored
!folder_that_should_not_be_ignored
```

Comment: It does not work. I tried running a ``git rm . -r --cached`` followed by a ``git add -A .`` afterwards, but it does not take all the files.