# Use `*.sh` in .gitignore but allow `A/B/C.sh` to be tracked

Tags: git, gitignore

**Note: I have removed this question from duplicate because while using !run.sh works for me, i am looking to allow any file in ansible/files as well.(Any file that i might add in the future.) The other solutions for the same that i found did not work for me.**

I want to exclude all `.sh` files from my repository, and for that i've used `*.sh` but then i want to include any file in `ansible/files`
Currently, my `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
# Ignore python environment
venv/

# Ignore .pyc files
*.pyc

# Ignore .log Files
*.log

# Ignore any __pycache__
__pycache__/

# Ignore .sh files
*.sh

# Allow any `.sh` file(s) in ansible/files folder
!/ansible/files/*.sh

# Allow any file(s) in ansible/files folder
!/ansible/files/*
```

But this isn't working, `ansible/files/run.sh` is a file that exists but doesn't get tracked.
Question: Why is `.gitignore` ignoring `!/ansible/files/*.sh` & `!/ansible/files/*`; how to allow any file in that folder to be tracked?

Note: I have removed this question from duplicate because while using !run.sh works for me, i am looking to allow any file in `ansible/files` as well.(Any file that i might add in the future.)
The other solutions for the same that i found did not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception)

Comment: Do `git check-ignore -v ansible/files/run.sh` to see what rule matches that file.  It's possible there's a `.gitignore` with an overriding rule in `ansible` or `ansible/files`, or perhaps there's some  trailing whitespace on the paths. It's going to be something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing a wildcard in front of the path. This is just an assumption but I doubt you ment to target `(root)/ansible`.

Try this:

```
# Allow any `.sh` file(s) in ansible/files folder
!*/ansible/files/*.sh

# Allow any file(s) in ansible/files folder
!*/ansible/files/*
```

Also, you have to change your rule for `*.sh` to the following:

```
# Ignore .sh files
*/*.sh
```

Comment: If i do `*/*.sh` it doesn't ignore other `.sh` files in `app/scripts/prod/run.sh` (Includes the files i want to include but also any files in second-sub-directory of any folder.)