# Did Git change the "!" prefix behavior at .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I found a below sentence in Git 2.7 Release Notes.

> - Allow a later "!/abc/def" to override an earlier "/abc" that
>     appears in the same .gitignore file to make it easier to express
>     "everything in /abc directory is ignored, except for ...".
>
>   [Git 2.7 Release Notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt)

However, This function seems to be invalid in subsequent versions.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.19.1
$  cat .gitignore
/abc
!/abc/def
$ mkdir abc
$ echo foo > abc/def
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Did Git change the "!" prefix behavior at .gitignore? Or did I mistake?

Comment: To expand a bit on jthill's answer: the item noted here did not actually work and was reverted in [commit 8c722360d1277259d4baec951e1488086f775214](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c722360d1277259d4baec951e1488086f775214).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like that change was reverted in 2.8.0, why are you combing two-year-old release notes to see how gitignore behaves when you could just say `git help ignore` and it'd tell you

> - An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. ***It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.*** Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".

The easy way to do your gitignores if you don't want the ignored-directory pruning is to ignore their entire contents with

```
directory/**
```

follwed by any overrides, (e.g. your `!directory/def`) and at the end of your gitignore put

```
!*/
```

followed by any complete exclusions you really meant for effect.

Comment: What I wanted to do is done in you way! But, I cant understand the purpose of the last `!*/`. It seems to move enough even without this on my environment.

Comment: A trailing slash is a directory-only marker, `*/` matches only directories, `!*/` says never match directories (unless a following match overrides it).