# git ignores my request for a file exception

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following configuration in my `.gitignore` file.

```
.idea/*
!.idea/inspectionProfiles/Teamcity.xml
!.idea/scopes/teamcity.xml
!.idea/runConfigurations/Watch_Sass_files.xml
```

It should be ignoring all the files in the .idea directory with 3 exceptions. It doesn't allow me to `git add` them. I have run `git check-ignore` on them and that's the message

> .gitignore:59:/.idea/*  .idea/runConfigurations/Watch_Sass_files.xml

I have even implemented @Matiss suggestion in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731573/9559251

It seems that you can make a directory exception but not file exceptions e.g.
`!.idea/runConfigurations/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work — unignoring directories ignored with `*`:

```
.idea/*
!.idea/inspectionProfiles/
!.idea/inspectionProfiles/Teamcity.xml
!.idea/scopes/
!.idea/scopes/teamcity.xml
!.idea/runConfigurations/
!.idea/runConfigurations/Watch_Sass_files.xml
```

Could be simplified as (unignore all directories):

```
.idea/*
!.idea/*/
!.idea/inspectionProfiles/Teamcity.xml
!.idea/scopes/teamcity.xml
!.idea/runConfigurations/Watch_Sass_files.xml
```

Comment: What if I only wanted to make exception to a single configuration file and not the whole directory. Would it work this way?

Comment: Initial `.idea/*` ignores all files. `!.idea/inspectionProfiles/` (or `!.idea/*/`) unignores directories but doesn't unignore files so files under `.idea/` are still ignored. Git doesn't track directories, it only track files. So there is nothing to worry.

Comment: Another approach would be to ignore everything `.idea/*` and force-add a single file: `git add --force .idea/scopes/teamcity.xml`. Tracked files are never ignored even if ignore patterns match. `.gitignore` only ignores untracked files.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are there's something else going on in your `.gitignore` that whatever you're using to view and edit it isn't showing you. Trailing white space (including bad line separators), weird character set, something.

Try `xxd -g8 -c32 .gitignore` (or use your hex dumper of choice, that's mine) and look for differences between what your editor shows you and the per-byte decode.