# Allowing exceptions with .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have two files in a config directory: local.config and local.config.example
I only want local.config.example to be in git and ignore local.config.

I tried the following to .gitignore, but this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
local.config
!local.config.example
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Approaches,

1. Simply add local.config in .gitignore

```
git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
    local.config.example

    cat .gitignore 
    local.config
```

2. As mentioned in [git ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Add the path(s) to your file(s) which you would like to ignore to your .gitignore file (and commit them).