# How to do exception in .gitignore if I am using wildcards for folder path in ignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am aware this was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3203228/1157814) and answered, however no answer covers when the ignoring line uses wildcards...

I have the following line in .gitignore:

```
**/_secrets
```

Now I would like to add one exception to this using the `!` syntax:

```
!**/_secrets/not_a_secret.txt
```

However this does not seem to work.

What I've tried:

```
!**/not_a_secret.txt
!**/_secrets/not_a_secret.txt
!(**/_secrets/not_a_secret.txt)
```

I've also tried to change `**/_secrets` to `**/_secrets/` still does not work, all files in the _secrets folder are ignored, **with no exception of not_a_secret.txt file**.

What am I missing?

Comment: Fwik the order matters. Make sure you first first have the exclusion, then the exception. There shouldn't be anything different with your case than with the answer you linked. The fact that you have ** shouldn't matter here I think.

Comment: Try `**/_secrets/*`

Comment: Also make sure you read the second answer to that question. It's important.

Comment: You *must not* ignore the `_secrets` directory itself, if you want Git to look *inside* the `_secrets` directory. That is, you want `**/_secrets/*` as @aerial301 suggested. Git will have to open and read each `_secrets` directory before decidng whether to ignore some file *in* that directory. The `*` will then ignore all those files, but the later `!` lines will override that for the specified files.

Comment: Many thx for All. Now I tried `**/_secrets/*`  and `!**/_secrets/not_a_secret.txt` in *both order* the file still ignored. I've also tested, if I comment out `**/_secrets/*` no files are ignored, so that is the line which effectively ignores the file and `!**/_secrets/not_a_secret.txt` makes no exclusion, with other words seems to be not working

Answer (score 2):

The general rule of gitignore is simple:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**

To exclude files (or all files) from a subfolder of an ignored folder `f`, you would do:

```
**/_secrets/
!**/_secrets/**/
!**/_secrets/**/not_a_secret.txt
```

Meaning: you need to whitelist *folders* first, before being able to exclude from `gitignore` *files*.

Comment: Many thx. I've tried exactly this three lines in an empty repo, with a .gitignore with only those three lines for the sake of isolate my issue. The `not_a_secret.txt`  **is still ignored**. Just for the check: if I comment out the `_secrets/` line, then no files in the folder are ignored....

Comment: I meant a freshly created repo with two files:  `/_secrets/mysecret.txt` and `/_secrets/not_a_secret.txt`

Comment: @g.pickardou I just amended the rules (and tested them in a dummy repo): they are now working as expected.

Comment: Many thx for you valuable time I do not want to abuse... I give up, and going to find a workaround, moving the file to other folder... still the same for me with the amended rule.

Comment: @g.pickardou Don't give up: I promise: those three rules are doing exactly what you requested in your question. No workaround required.

Comment: @g.pickardou Unless... what is your Git version? What does `git version` return?

Comment: git version 2.30.2.windows.1

Comment: @g.pickardou Perfect: it should work just fine with this version.