# Git Ignore for whole folder except for sub folder?

Tags: git

Currently I have this folder

`/public/images`

Where all images are being stored

But I have this 1 sub folder inside of `images` folder named as `mycta`

It is possible to ignore all files inside of `/public/images`

except for this directory `/public/images/mycta`?

As of now I have this `/public/images` in my gitignore file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exceptions in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415873/exceptions-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a *negative ignore pattern* to your `.gitignore` file using a `!` as follows:

#### .gitignore

```
/public/images/*
!/public/images/mycta
```

But note that instead of ignoring the whole parent directory you must ignore the contents, adding a `*` to that line, because as `man gitignore` says re `!`:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.