# Update Code from Git/Bitbucket to live server

Tags: version-control, github, bitbucket

How can i update my live server with the changes i made through Git/Bitbucket?

Is there any free service ?

Is it possible to do it with some kind of API which can be integrated with cronjob?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [BitBucket service hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Managing+bitbucket+Services).
They are illustrated in "[Using Bitbucket for Automated Deployments](http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/)", and that article uses the [POST service](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+Service+Management).

> Bitbucket POSTs to the service URL you specify.
>   The service receives an `POST` whenever user pushes to the repository.
>   The content header of the `POST` has an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` type.
>   This services behaves similarly to an HTTP publish/subscribe service.
>   The payload has `payload=` prepended to the actual payload. The payload is url encode content.
>
> The body of POST request contains information about the repository where the change originated, a list of recent commits, and the user that made the push.

---

Regarding GitHub, see [this process](https://gist.github.com/1809044) which describes how to use the [**Post-receive** hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks)

[image: WebHookURLs]

Comment: Thank for this. And what about Github. Or any fee tools ?

Comment: Thanks for that. And what if i want to transfer the files to webserver? is it possible ?

Comment: @NikhilMohan one way would be for your post to trigger on the server a script which would git fetch from GitHub/BitBucket and then checkout in the live server repo. See the links in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732851/maintain-multiple-simultaneously-accessible-versions-of-website-remotely-using-g/12740518#12740518