# how to push code form bitbucket to amaozn EC2 server

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

I have created a laravel application and want to now push my code to a staging server.

In my amazon AWS account I have created an EC2 server, RDS and VPC. I have my code on my bitbucket account. All I want to do is push my code from bitbucket to my EC2 server. However, after looking for hours I cannot find a simple way to do this, and find it confusing.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/announcing-atlassian-bitbucket-support-for-aws-codedeploy/

Comment: doesnt that push it to s3 bucket though? i want it to push to my ec2 server

Comment: You can get that code to your EC2 instance using AWS S3 sync command cron.

Comment: Did you look at this service? https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/ Also Jenkins, Codeship, TeamCity, etc.

Comment: i have followed the bitbucket tutorial, tried to create an applciation in code deploy, and then when trying to attach a service role arn i get the following error: Cannot assume role provided.

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243694/update-code-from-git-bitbucket-to-live-server)