# ignore folders using .gitignore?

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignoring directories in Git repos on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows)

I have a few folders, cache scattered throughout a webapp.

I am tracking the project with Git.

I have added empty index.html files to each cache folder.

I want to ignore all contents of the `cache` folders, but by default the folders are empty, hence the reason for the index.html.

I have tried

```
*cache/*
!*cache/index.html
```

But it is not ignoring them.