# How to ignore a specific project with .gitignore

Tags: c#, git, github, project, gitignore

I have the following solution structure

```
SlnFolder/
    Project1/
    Project2ToBeExcluded/
    Project3/
    .gitignore
```

I copied [this](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) .gitignore as a basis. What I try to achieve is adding `Project2ToBeExcluded` to .gitignore. I tried to add `Project2ToBeExcluded/` at the very top of the .gitignore but the project and its changes still are tracked. By either the GitHub application and my VS2012 extension. How to fix this?

Comment: Ignore it like you would a `bin` or `obj` directory. `Project2ToBeExcluded/` (with the forward slash).

Comment: Related: [ignore folders using .gitignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259778/ignore-folders-using-gitignore)

Comment: I have tried exactly this and it doesn't work! Do I need to update my tools accordingly (I restarted them multiple times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already add those files to the repository before adding the .gitignore file?  If so, see [.gitignore file not ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring).  You'll need to clear the cache or update the index.  The link has both options to try.

Comment: After I have commited the changes on .gitignore to my repository, everything worked well. Thanks!