# How do I ignore files with a .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

Always when I run `git status` some files are listed as untracked, that is how it should be. But I would like to not have them listed there everytime I run `git status`. As what I have understood, I should add those files to an `.gitignore`-file.

In my project I have a file `.classpath` and a directory `.gradle/*` that I want to ingore.

My `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
.classpath
.gradle/*
```

but these files are still listed as "untracked" when I run `git status`. Is there anything wrong with my `.gitignore` file or how should I fix this?

---

Here is my `git status` output:

```
C:\myproject>git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   src/Test.java
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .classpath
#       .gitignore
#       .gradle/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: uhm weird, it should already ignore them, try to add a slash in front of each entry...

Comment: The gitignore you posted works perfectly fine; i just tried it. Please include your `git status` output in the question. It sounds a bit like you already added the file.

Comment: Been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working

Comment: @ThiefMaster ok, I added `git status` output

Comment: @brk3: it seem to be the same problem, but that solution doesn't work for me. So it's unsolved, so far.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows?

Comment: @ThiefMaster that question doesn't help me. I created the file this way: http://superuser.com/a/498909/27037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the paths in my `.gitignore` file had a space in the end of each row. When I removed the space char from each line in `.gitignore` it worked fine. This is how I created my `.gitignore` file:

https://superuser.com/a/498909/27037

```
echo .classpath> .gitignore
echo .gradle/*>> .gitignore
```

and before I used this commands (does not work):

```
echo .classpath > .gitignore
echo .gradle/* >> .gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
.classpath
.gradle/
```

Make sure you `git add .` to stage the .gitignore file.