# .gitignore a folder content

Tags: git, gitignore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignoring directories in Git repos on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows)

My web app has the following directory layout:

```
myapp/
    .gitignore
    .git/
        ...

    static/
            mytest.txt
            fgs.ico
    ledgerware/
        static/
            mytest.txt
            fgs.ico
        ...
```

I'd like to edit existing myapp/.gitignore file so that when git push it ignores all files inside myapp/ledgerware/static folder, but NOT myapp/static folder. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/343646/1947535) and the [git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the one listed above.  The answers in the linked answer do not apply to this particular case.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Just make the line in `.gitignore` as specific as you want it to be:

```
ledgerware/static/*
```

Comment: If OP need to ignore the folder itself as well, the `*` can be removed from the end of the line. And alternatively, OP could also put a local `.gitignore` file in `ledgerware/` which ignores `static/*`.

Comment: If everything is ignored inside a folder then that folder is empty.  Aren't empty folders ignored by git automatically?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Calkins yes they are, but you're talking about an egg popping out an egg here. git first has to ignore the contents of a folder before it can be seen as empty by git. the folder's probably not empty while running the project, probably a folder to hold environment specific files and working files or output, so we don't want to commit our output, we just want the folder

Comment: Does not work.  The directory despite having contents, is not added at all, but is totally ignored (with the contents all being ignored).

Comment: @m.brindley : not true. I had to append the * to a folder in order to have the folder content excluded but the folder (and a file `.gitkeep`)  included. git version 2.34.1.windows.1