# How to exclude non-project files from git commit in PyCharm?

Tags: git, pycharm, gitlab, git-commit

I have a project setup, where I have one git repo with two folders in it. Each folder is a separate project in PyCharm. Both projects are connected to that repo.
When I update the code of one project, the other project notices that and adds the files from the other project to **its own** commit options:

[image]

The yellow/orange highlighted files are non-project files, and I only want the project to automatically add files to commit that are included in the project. I can of course just choose the files I want to commit, but sometimes I miss a file, which is problematic, and it would be nice if I didn't have to select files each time.

So, is there a way to exclude non-project files from commit options by default?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `.gitignore` file in the repo where git is working and add the locations of the non-project files or folders you don't want to be included in the commit. More info [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700835/gitignore-a-folder-content)