# What is syntax for ignoring a directory in Git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

When I want to add an entire directory to my .gitignore, what is the syntax? The directory-to-ignore is in my root directory.

Should it be:

1) `directory-to-ignore`

2) `directory-to-ignore/`

3) `directory-to-ignore/*`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring directories in Git repos on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add the directory to the .gitigore like:

.gitignore file:

```
directory-to-ignore/
```

so, option **2** is correct

Comment: yep. what he said. here's another same S.O. question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows/343734#343734

Comment: @oyvey, oy vey! nice find. yom tov.

Comment: since the OP mentions that the folder is in his [repo's] root directory, it might be worth adding that a leading slash will prevent other subfolders of the same name to be ignored (i.e. `/directory-to-ignore/`)