# Anyway to tell git not to take a whole folder?

Tags: git, apache-flex, version-control

I am working on a Flex project in git and I am trying to find a why for git to know checking the generated files from flex.

I want everything in

**Flex/src**

checked in to git but I dont want

**Flex/src/generated/**

Can I do this in git?

Comment: Please see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a .gitignore file.  You can add a .gitignore file to the root of your repository, containing this single line of text:

- `/Flex/src/generated`

Git will then ignore all files in /Flex/src/generated directory. Git doesn't really differentiate between folders and files.

Reference: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Possible duplicate: [Ignoring directories in Git repos on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows?lq=1)