# how to get git to ignore a file (wild card files)

Tags: git

I have a pile of files that are in the physical location:

```
C:\VCProject\SVCodeCampWeb\WebAPI\ExtJsAppsSrc\CCApp23\resources\sass\.sass-cache\ec980567a9be72757a9921ebeae5bb3621e2b262\_IndexBar.scssc
```

my git root is at ExtJSAppSrc

I would expect that I could ignore all the files in the .sass-cache directory with the .gitignore line

```
CCApp23/resources/sass/.sass-cache*
```

but that does not seem to work.

Suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `CApp23/resources/sass/.sass-cache/*`?

Comment: Even `CApp23/resources/sass/.sass-cache/` should suffice.

Comment: It might be that you are using / instead of \ , but I'm not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring directories in Git repos on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows)

Comment: @devnull Yes, if the folder should be ignored as well.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/gitignore-file-syntax

Comment: Git will ignore only **untracked** files, if you have added those files into repository, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/removing-a-file-from-git-source-control-but-not-from-the-source/936290#936290)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `gitignore`:

```
/CCApp23/resources/sass/.sass-cache/
```

Or, to ignore the contents of all `.sass-cache` directories:

```
.sass-cache/
```