# how to commit only one component javascript file in git

Tags: git

i have to commit the javascript file of only one component(ReactJS) in git..what is the command used for that..

my modified file which is located in `E:\project\work\src\components\administration.js`

please help me whether
the below command is right or not?

```
git commit E:\project\work\src\components\administration.js -m "userAdminChanges"
```

Comment: `git add filename` `git commit -m "magic changes"`

Comment: also get familiar with some graphical git frontend. On windows IMO [GitExtention](http://gitextensions.github.io/) is the best. Doing commits there is very user friedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, when i want to commit only one file i do:

**git add E:\project\work\src\components\administration.js**

**git commit -m "UserAdminChanges"**

hope that can help you !

Have a good day

Comment: @catherine yep ! or just git push

Comment: Thanks  a lot...committed successfully

Comment: You should explain what `git add` does, to not end up running sets of commands blindly.

Comment: @ PAYRE Quentin  i have one more doubt , if i want to exclude one folder named config from committing to git... how to achieve that?

Comment: @catherine Create a file named .gitignore in your project's directory. Ignore directories by entering the directory name into the file (with a slash appended) (link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repos-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to `stage` your changes, to tell Git: "This is what I want to commit", it is done with the `add` command, and it is to be done regardless of if the file is new or not:

```
git add E:\project\work\src\components\administration.js
```

You can stage multiple changes in multiple steps before commiting:

```
# Edit file1
# Stage it:
git add file1
# Edit file2
# Stage it:
git add file2

# Commits all staged changes (changes in file1 and file2):
git commit -m "Description about those changes"
```

For reference: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository