# Can I ignore a specific project in a .Net solution when using git?

Tags: .net, git

I have a .Net solution with multiple projects, for example, project `A`, `B` and `C`.

`B` and `C` are dependencies of `A`. That means without `A`, `B` and `C` could be compiled as well.

There are some special configurations in project `A`, so I want to exclude project `A` when uploading to Github repository.

If I just set the project folder name in `.gitignore` then I will get error while compiling the solution from Git.
What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring directories in Git repositories on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repositories-on-windows)

Comment: Sorry, nope. I do know how to ignore directories in a git repo, but I want to know how to solve the potential problems that @felipe-oriani said below.

Comment: You might get better answers if you added the actual reason for having the project but not adding it to the repo

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize the projects in one folder each one and ignore the folder. On the `.gitignore` file:

```
/Project.Web/*
```

Considering the directory `Project.Web` is ion the root of the repository, everything under the `Project.Web` path would be ignored.

Potential Problems:

1. If your solution file `.sln` references a project that may be not exists on the structure
2. You could not be able to compile until you remove it from the sln.
3. It also could be a reference to other projects in the same solution which also could avoid to compile.

If you just want to make possible the compilation, generate the dependent assembly you want to ignore and switch the reference from the project in solution to the generated assembly. It will make the compilation possible and you will not be exposing your code.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I want to know how to solve those potential problems that you mentioned.

Comment: I updated my anwser but you will need to change some settings on your code.